# Does [status-declined] mean absolutely no?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

I was just reading [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)'s info page, which states,

> This tag is used to denote either:
>
> - [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)s that will not be implemented *at the present time*
> - and [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug)s that will not be fixed *as of now*.
>
> ...

<sup>(Emphasis mine.)</sup>

So, does that mean a FR/BR *could* be tagged with [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) and then later on, actually get implemented/fixed and tagged with [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)? And are there any examples of this happening before?

Comment: nothing mean absolutely no.  The most famous one was the ability to retract close votes, which was famously declined by Jeff, but the SE team decided to implement last year.

Comment: [Turns out, I wrote that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/62907/revisions) - so take it with a grain of salt. I may just like using weasel words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that *theoretically speaking*, the feature request or bug is revisited and implemented anyway. *No* doesn't mean *No, indefinitely*.

This has happened, see [this SEDE query for Meta Stack Exchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/206569). There 126 examples of posts that once were marked as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) but are now marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). In some cases the post got *both* tags (partially declined, partially completed).

Some examples:

- [Can we have the ability to retract a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)
- [Should StackOverflow support more than 2 openids per account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/should-stackoverflow-support-more-than-2-openids-per-account)
- [How about a "Vote not to close" option to counter the "Vote to close"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close)